# Access internet via Samsung LTE USB modem

Tags: linux, networking, mobile-broadband, usb-modem

I have a Samsung LTE USB modem connected on Ubuntu. The tool for using this modem creates a TAP interface (`tap1`) and I can successfully receive an IP address using `dhclient`. I am trying to access the internet via this TAP interface but could not figure out how.

Is it necessary to bridge `tap1` with `eth0` and then access internet via `eth0`?

I’m trying to follow [this guide](https://github.com/P1sec/LTE_monitor_c2xx).

Here’s the `dmesg` output when connecting the modem:

```
usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6889
usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
kalmia_init_and_get_ethernet_addr
c2xx debug ON
kalmia 3-1:1.0 wwan0: register 'kalmia' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, Samsung Kalmia LTE USB dongle, 60:a1:0a:97:29:52
option 3-1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
usb 3-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Comment: I never heard of a TAP interface when using a mobile data modem. Could you please add the output of `dmesg` when connecting the modem? To simplify things, run `dmesg --clear` before connecting the modem. /edit: Oh yeah, and an example of the assigned IP address please. :)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9675890/

Comment: I think this guide does way more than what you actually want. Anyway, from how I understand it, you should be good to go the moment to obtain an IP address with `dhclient`. Could you please update your question to include the output of `netstat -rn` (after connecting)?

Comment: yes. Problem solved by just making the default route to be tap1 interface. sudo route add default dev tap1.

Comment: Well, that’s now exactly how it’s supposed to work, but congrats anyway. You should add it as an answer. After a cooldown time passes (a day IIRC), you then mark your own answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is <s>two</s> few ways to do this.

1. If you want to have L2 access: create bridge (apt-get install bridge-utils;brctl addbr foo;brctl addif tap1; brctl addif eth0).
2. You can enable routing & NAT (sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i eth0 -j MASQUERADE  (or -i tap1, depends on direction).
3. You can set up higher levels (like squid for http proxying).

Basically, you didn't say what you got and what you want.

Comment: I am trying to access internet via tap1 just like how we do via wlan0 and eth0. tap1 is holding an ip address of the 4g modem connected via usb.

Comment: Who create tap interface? TAP is 'virtual ethernet' interface and it always created by some application. Just show ip link, ip addr and ip route commands.